# определение, уточнение, пояснение - что правильно?

Tags: определения

Он подозревается в присвоении имущества в крупном размере – на сумму более 10 миллионов долларов, а также в легализации денежных средств. С помощью тире обособляется несогласованное определение к слову "размере", но второе тире опускается, так как после определения стоит запятая?
Можно ли так объяснить постановку первого тире и отсутствие второго?

Но по Розенталю выделяется с помощью тире несогласованное определение, если оно выражено инфинитивом. Здесь же нет инфинитива.

Значит, правильно объяснить постановку тире (но уже двух) так можно:

1.Он подозревается в присвоении имущества в крупном размере – на сумму более 10 миллионов долларов, - а также в легализации денежных средств. С помощью тире обособляется вставка со значением уточнения (или пояснения?).

Или же можно обособить скобками:

2.Он подозревается в присвоении имущества в крупном размере (на сумму более 10 миллионов долларов), а также в легализации денежных средств. С помощью тире обособляется вставка со значением уточнения (или пояснения?).

Какой из этих вариантов (и объяснений) правильный? Или возможны все три?

Answer (score 3):

1) Обособляться с помощью тире могут любые определения, если (по замыслу автора или по структуре предложения) они являются добавочными сообщениями, например:  Осенние зори **иные** – **хмурые, медленные.** **Лесные** щеглы кормились здесь среди всякой травяной всячины – **весёлые, никогда не унывающие.** 
Это пояснительные определения в добавочном сообщении, оформленные как присоединительные.

2) Он подозревается в присвоении имущества в **крупном размере** – на сумму более 10 миллионов долларов, а также в легализации денежных средств. Это та же конструкция, то есть пояснение со значением присоединения. Интонация встроенная, поэтому одно тире.

3) Можно ли сделать такое определение вставкой? Вероятно, да. Тогда это будет интонация исключения (выделение паузами с двух сторон, общий пониженный тон).

4) Но вот обособить вставку лучше скобками, такая графика более удобна для чтения.